# using realloc won't store values in array after exiting the funcion

Tags: c, realloc

After puting the values in data base in an array and sending the values to `addReader` within the function itself ,the values are stored successfully , however when going back to main the entered values are gone.

Given the following code : creating the dynamic array with `realloc`

```
reader* readerBuilder(reader *rdr, int *readNum){       //building all the readers
    FILE *read;
    int i=1;
    char *str;
    read = fopen("Readers.txt","r");
    checkFile(read);
    str = readFromFile(read);
    while(str != NULL)
    {
        rdr[i-1] = *cutToRdr(str);
        str = readFromFile(read);
        if(str != NULL){
            i++;
            rdr = (reader*)realloc(rdr,sizeof(reader)*i);
            checkreader(rdr);
        }
    }
    fclose(read);
    *readNum = i;
    return rdr;
}
```

Given the calling function :

```
reader* addReader(reader *rdr, int *readNum){       //adding a reader from the user
    char string[1000];
    rdr = (reader*)realloc(rdr,sizeof(reader)*(*readNum+1));// build new struct array ( bigger), with the old values
    checkreader(rdr);// check if can get memory
    printf("please enter the I.D. of the student you want to add:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum].id=cutToStr(string);// put id in struct
    printf("please add the reader's first name:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum].first_name=cutToStr(string);// put first name in struct
    printf("please add the reader's last name:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum].last_name=cutToStr(string);// put last name in struct
    printf("please add the reader's address:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum].address=cutToStr(string);// put adress in struct
    printf("please add the reader's phone:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum].phone=cutToStr(string);// put phone in struct
    rdr[*readNum].numToTake = 5;// change value of numbers to tke to 5
    *readNum = *readNum + 1;// rise the number of the readers
    return rdr;// return the new structs array
}
```

Given the calling for function in main:

```
rdr=addReader(rdr,readNum);
```

Defenition of the reader struct :

```
typedef struct reader{
    int numToTake;
    char *first_name, *last_name, *address, *phone, *id;
}reader;
```

What am i doing wrong ?
Regards,David

EDIT!

Still doesn't work.
The new edition of the code :

```
void addReader(reader **rdr, int *readNum){     //adding a reader from the user
    char string[1000];
    rdr = (reader**)realloc(rdr,sizeof(reader*)*(*readNum+1));// build new struct array ( bigger), with the old values
    checkreader(*rdr);// check if can get memory
    printf("please enter the I.D. of the student you want to add:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum]->id=cutToStr(string);// put id in struct
    printf("please add the reader's first name:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum]->first_name=cutToStr(string);// put first name in struct
    printf("please add the reader's last name:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum]->last_name=cutToStr(string);// put last name in struct
    printf("please add the reader's address:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum]->address=cutToStr(string);// put adress in struct
    printf("please add the reader's phone:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);// get from operant
    rdr[*readNum]->phone=cutToStr(string);// put phone in struct
    rdr[*readNum]->numToTake = 5;// change value of numbers to tke to 5
    *readNum = *readNum + 1;// rise the number of the readers
    //return rdr;// return the new structs array
```

}

The new calling in main  :

```
addReader(&rdr,readNum);
```

Comment: What does `cutToStr` do? If it returns a pointer to the same string, then this string will be overwritten again and again. And is `readerBuilder` even used? and how is `rdr` passed to `addReader` initialized?

Comment: The "cutstr" get static array of chars and return pointer to dynamic allocated char * ( used for the cells of the struct ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing `**rdr`:

```
reader* addReader(reader **rdr, int *readNum)
                         ^^
```

Also, this adds a new indirection level when you `realloc`.

With the code you have now you `realloc` on a copy of the pointer not the actual pointer.

Comment: Can you please explain why ** instead of one * ?

Comment: @zahidavid: search pass by value vs pass by reference in c/c++.

Comment: I understand now, thank you . Isn't there any other way to do that without using ** (pointer to pointer) ?